# Elastic search bulk api specify update/create behavior for each source/record

Tags: elasticsearch

Somewhere I got the impression that I have the options of both "create" and "create or update". I would like to be able to specify the behavior on _id conflicts for each source in a bulk upload. Some of them should should create if the identified record does not exist and update if it does. Others should create if the record does not exists and do nothing if it does.

The example below seems to do an "update or create"

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
```

Hopefully this will only "create" and not update if a record exists for the index/type/id

```
{ "create" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "field1" : "value3" }
```

I'm open to suggestion of the best way to make this happen. I'll post whatever I figure out if someone doesn't get there first.

Answer (score 0):

I think that operation type feature should answer.

Extract from [doc](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/index_.html)

Operation Type
The index operation also accepts an `op_type` that can be used to force a create operation, allowing for **put-if-absent** behavior. When create is used, the index operation will fail if a document by that id already exists in the index.

Here is an example of using the `op_type` parameter:

```
$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1?op_type=create' -d '{
    "user" : "kimchy",
    "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
    "message" : "trying out Elastic Search"
}'
```

Another option to specify create is to use the following URI:

```
$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1/_create' -d '{
    "user" : "kimchy",
    "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
    "message" : "trying out Elastic Search"
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will be able to do this in 2.0 with the scripting feature. https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/2008

Right now I am doing it with two requests. Frist a _create to add any new documents and then a update to make changes to existing documents.